# Allow users to upload image in shopify

Tags: e-commerce, shopify, liquid, shopify-activemerchant

Is there any way i can allow users to upload images to a contest page in shopify users. I have searched a lot but no luck with shopify discussion forum or any thread. 
Basically, I Want to allow users to upload images and those images need to be appear(after admin approval) in contest page for voting. Users can also vote for the best images available in Contest page.

Is there any app or do i need to do it manually?

Comment: There is probably an app to do this but I have also been meaning to create something like this and haven't got around to it yet. I'll let you know my findings.

Comment: I feel like a good approach would be to use SendGrid API or something to send the image to a chosen email. They can then be curated and added to the store. That way you can you the email as the file host.

Comment: It can be possible through app which have alone admin and what ever you want to do you can do.

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation says to use a jot form. lol.

https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/communication/let-customers-upload-files

Here is some documentation for customisation which has the ability to upload files.
https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/products/get-customization-information-for-products

This can be done on a cart page. Althought because you can make an unlimited number of cart templates it doesn't really have to be a cart. Or you can do it on the product page using `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on your file upload form.